# Launching SMath

Tags: 13.04

I am trying to find a way to launch SMath without the terminal. Currently I can only launch it through the terminal with

```
sudo mono /usr/local/SMath/SMathStudio_Desktop.exe
```

How can I lock it to the launcher on the side so it is easier to start. Please note that I am very new to Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shortcut on the Desktop by using `gnome-desktop-item-edit` in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) as follow (note that if you don't have installed the package `gnome-desktop-item-edit`, you must be install first, so if you have `gnome-shell` or `gnome-tweak-tool` installed, then it is installed automatically):

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will start the dialog (Create Launcher):

[image: Create Launcher]

Insert for **Name** any name you want (for example 'SMath') and for **Command** `sudo mono /usr/local/SMath/SMathStudio_Desktop.exe` and press **Ok**.

You can put this `.desktop` file in any folder, and then drag and drop to the Launcher.

[image: SMath]

Thanks to [Binarylife](https://askubuntu.com/users/4937/binarylife) for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78968/147044).